# Is it possible to control animation using QGraphicsSvgItem?

Tags: c++, qt, animation

Is it possible to perform animation using SVG (QGraphicsSvgItem, SvgRenderer) and then control it also ?

I know that animation is possible, but I do not know how to control it.

An example will be great.

Comment: What do you mean to control the animation?

Comment: @eyllanesc e.g if I want to change the color of only element or pause the animation for some time.